# Can we send editable forms in a group chat via xmpp ios?

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, instant-messaging

I need to implement groupChat and exchange different format of data between chat users for which I will be using xmpp alongwith swift technology for the iOS client end . The app requires exchange of editable form with 8 - 10 data fields between group chat users.

For example :- If User-A starts by sending an empty form, now every user will be able to see the form and suppose User-B edits/fill the form, now the updated form will be shown to every user.

My simple question is if it is possible using xmpp and swift . If yes then should i stick to the technology i have mentioned or i have to change it. Thank you.

Comment: See http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0004.html